# Envelope is not configured for support of recipient signing providers

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send an envelope to be signed via digital certificate, I am receiving the following message.

> com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body:

```
{
  "errorCode":"SIGNATURE_PROVIDER_INVALID_FOR_NONSBS",
  "message":"Signature providers are not valid for this recipient. Standards Based Signatures must be enabled for the sending account. Envelope is not configured for support of recipient signing providers"
}
```

**Here is code:**

```
private EnvelopeDefinition makeEnvelope(WorkArguments args, Object resumo) throws IOException {

    Tabs signerTabs = EnvelopeHelpers.createSignerTabs(EnvelopeHelpers.createSignHere("**signature_1**", ANCHOR_OFFSET_Y, ANCHOR_OFFSET_X));

    Signer signer = new Signer();
    signer.setEmail(resumo.getMail();
    signer.setName(resumo.getName());
    signer.setRecipientId("1");
    signer.setRoutingOrder("1");
    signer.setTabs(signerTabs);

    RecipientSignatureProvider provider = new RecipientSignatureProvider();
    // provider.setSignatureProviderName("UniversalSignaturePen_ICP_SmartCard_TSP");
    provider.setSignatureProviderName("UniversalSignaturePen_ImageOnly");

    List<RecipientSignatureProvider> lstProvider = new ArrayList<RecipientSignatureProvider>();
    lstProvider.add(provider);
    signer.setRecipientSignatureProviders(lstProvider);

    EnvelopeDefinition envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    envelope.setEmailSubject("Email Test");
    envelope.setDocuments(Arrays.asList(EnvelopeHelpers.createDocumentFromFile(resumo.getDirRel(), resumo.getDisplayName(),"1")));
    envelope.setRecipients(EnvelopeHelpers.createRecipients(signer));

    envelope.setStatus(EnvelopeHelpers.ENVELOPE_STATUS_SENT);

    return envelope;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by a missing/not enabled plan feature. You will need to contact [sales team](https://www.docusign.com/contact-sales) and check with them if SBS - Standard Based Signature is included in your plan